# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' reason: 'PushKit'

Tags: swift, twilio, xcode11

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'PushKit apps that use VoIP push must link either CallKit or IncomingCallNotifications frameworks.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23baa1ee __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23ba9f68 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff25614de9 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 191
    4   PushKit                             0x00007fff2af1896f +[PKPushRegistry _checkIfNecessaryVoIPFrameworksAreLinked] + 251
    5   PushKit                             0x00007fff2af18cdc -[PKPushRegistry _registerForPushType:] + 287
    6   PushKit                             0x00007fff2af1975f __38-[PKPushRegistry setDesiredPushTypes:]_block_invoke + 240
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b470d6c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b47f9fd _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 132
    9   PushKit                             0x00007fff2af1964e -[PKPushRegistry setDesiredPushTypes:] + 108
    10  Office Phone                        0x0000000109752139 $s12Office_Phone18MainViewControllerC5coderACSgSo7NSCoderC_tcfc + 2857
    11  Office Phone                        0x00000001097524e3 $s12Office_Phone18MainViewControllerC5coderACSgSo7NSCoderC_tcfcTo + 51
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471e7350 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2427
    13  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff46a37cd6 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 744
    14  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff46a379e1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 251
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471eb657 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 125
    16  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff46a37cd6 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 744
    17  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff46a37f7d UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1423
    18  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff46a379e1 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 251
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471e641e -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 450
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff471e918d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1145
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff476db470 -[UIStoryboard __reallyInstantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:creator:storyboardSegueTemplate:sender:] + 279
    22  Office Phone                        0x000000010976d750 $s12Office_Phone11AppDelegateC21selectVCToBedisplayed2vcySo16UIViewControllerCSg_tF + 464
    23  Office Phone                        0x000000010976d38f $s12Office_Phone11AppDelegateC22setUpInitialRootScreenyyF + 511
    24  Office Phone                        0x00000001097708ec $s12Office_Phone11AppDelegateC22requestForVerifyDeviceyyFy9Alamofire12DataResponseVyypGcfU_ + 2828
    25  Alamofire                           0x0000000109b72591 $s9Alamofire11DataRequestC8response5queue0D10Serializer17completionHandlerACXDSo012OS_dispatch_E0CSg_xyAA0B8ResponseVy16SerializedObjectQzGctAA0bkF8ProtocolRzlFyycfU_yycfU_ + 369
    26  Alamofire                           0x0000000109b2c22d $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b46fdf8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b470d6c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    29  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010b47ee24 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1500
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b0ce49 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b07aa9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2329
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23b06e66 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    33  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38346bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff47578dd0 UIApplicationMain + 1621
    35  Office Phone                        0x000000010977320b main + 75
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff516ecd29 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `CallKit Framework` in your project `Framework,Libraries, and Embeded Content` section.